# cURL - Not Working - WARNING: failed to save cookies in cookie.txt

Tags: php, http, curl

I'm totally new to cURL but here's what I'm wanting to do:

One of my suppliers has a product feed that I can download once I login to their site. This is ok but I want to automate it so I've tried to put the following script together (google and Stack info) - I've changed the username and password for security reasons but I'm 100% sure they're correct:

```
<?php

//The username or email address of the account.
define('USERNAME', 'myusername');

//The password of the account.
define('PASSWORD', 'mypassword');

//Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome ;)
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');

//Where our cookie information will be stored (needed for authentication).
define('COOKIE_FILE', '/cookie.txt');

//URL of the login form.
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://www.treatgifts.com/customer/sign-in.aspx');

//Login action URL. Sometimes, this is the same URL as the login form.
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://www.treatgifts.com/customer/sign-in.aspx');


$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); // file to write request header for debug purpose


//Get __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];

$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); // file to write request header for debug purpose


 //Start Login process

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_FORM_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array(
    'ctl00$BodyContentHolder$ucSecureSignInPrompt$txtCustomerEmail' => USERNAME,
    'ctl00$BodyContentHolder$ucSecureSignInPrompt$txtCustomerPassword' => PASSWORD,

'tl00$BodyContentHolder$ucSecureSignInPrompt$btnLogin'=>'LOGIN',
    'ctl00$BodyContentHolder$ucSecureSignInPrompt$txtCustomerEmail' => USERNAME,
    'ctl00$BodyContentHolder$ucSecureSignInPrompt$txtCustomerPassword' => PASSWORD,
'ctl00$ToolkitScriptManager1'=>'ctl00$BodyContentHolder$CartStatusUpdatePanel|ctl00$BodyContentHolder$ucSecureSignInPrompt$btnLogin'


);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); // Get result after login page.
print $ret; ?>
```

When I run the code it just directs me to the login page, without logging me in. I write the log to a file and here is what I get:

```
*   Trying 89.151.77.75...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.treatgifts.com (89.151.77.75) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL; CN=www.treatgifts.com
*  start date: Apr 20 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 19 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.treatgifts.com" matched cert's "www.treatgifts.com"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /customer/sign-in.aspx HTTP/1.1

Host: www.treatgifts.com

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36

Accept: */*

Referer: https://www.treatgifts.com/customer/sign-in.aspx

Content-Length: 758

Expect: 100-continue

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------58b9f0207a2bb57b



< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK

< Cache-Control: private

< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5

* Added cookie ASP.NET_SessionId="ehavykaxsnimn15gngsavho1" for domain www.treatgifts.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ehavykaxsnimn15gngsavho1; path=/; HttpOnly

< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

* Added cookie VTN="f818033a-08f4-401c-a6c9-d59688fad66b-0028710" for domain www.treatgifts.com, path /, expire 1529020828
< Set-Cookie: VTN=f818033a-08f4-401c-a6c9-d59688fad66b-0028710; expires=Fri, 15-Jun-2018 00:00:28 GMT; path=/

* Added cookie USID="ehavykaxsnimn15gngsavho1" for domain www.treatgifts.com, path /, expire 1529020828
< Set-Cookie: USID=ehavykaxsnimn15gngsavho1; expires=Fri, 15-Jun-2018 00:00:28 GMT; path=/

< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

< Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2018 00:00:28 GMT

< Content-Length: 23444

< 

* Connection #0 to host www.treatgifts.com left intact
* WARNING: failed to save cookies in cookie.txt
```

As you can see there is a warning at the bottom, which I suspect is causing the issue? What I've tried to do to fix this is:

- manually create cookie.txt andgive it 777 permissions.
- use the absolute path

None of these have worked.

I also don't see a POST command in console

Can anyone offer any advise?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: `/cookie.txt` will refer to the root doc of your vhost, which where u don't have permissions to write to. Change it `define('COOKIE_FILE', __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt');`

Comment: Using `/cookie.txt` is problematic, as this file would be in the root directory. But you write you already tried an absolute path, which also didn't work. What was the path exactly? Did the file already exist, with permissions 777?

Comment: Brilliant, adding `define('COOKIE_FILE', __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt');` worked. Although I still can't see any post actions, suggesting my username and password aren't being sent?

Comment: Cookies are never in the post data, they are just included in the headers of the request.

Comment: Small how-to automate this. You don't send/store your username/password in the cookie file, you first need to simulate the login by posting your username/password to the login page of the website. Because you defined the cookiejar, curl will store the session id cookie in there. In each next curl request u make, just add the cookiejar and the session cookie will make sure u are logged in and be able to make the request

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee, I understand that, but in my code I have `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch)` which should POST the data? But when I view it in console, there are only GET methods